# PHP to search inside 30,000 text files

Tags: php, file, search, text

I have a directory of about 30,000 text files and I'd like to search inside each to find if they contain a specified text.   How can I do this effectively in PHP?

Comment: Do a system call to grep. Seriously.

Comment: Why are you using PHP for this?

Comment: This sounds like a question that was posted fairly recently..... the answer is still "don't use PHP" -- or use PHP to call something that isn't PHP.

Comment: For the most performant solution, you need to hand over the job to a tool that is designed for this purpose. Something much faster than `grep`. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40773407/65732

Comment: This question pops up first when you search for "php to search inside file" @ stack's search box. And all I can say: WOW. Good old days when offtopic answers were actually TOLERATED and even ACCEPTED :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`grep` is your friend. You can use one of php's functions that allow execution of external commands to call it, if for some reason you need the result inside a PHP script.

Comment: If he's really got 30k files, he would need to `grep -r [exp] folder-with-30k-files/` , or he's going to blow the system's ARG_MAX limit, where grep would just say "too many arguments".

Comment: @Tim: Can always use `xargs` to feed filenames to it.

Answer (score 1):

1) Use grep as mentioned above

2) Cache the search results so you don't have to search 30,000 text files for the same search term again.

Answer (score 0):

As the others have said, grep is your friend, do a system call for it.

Answer (score 0):

Also, consider building a search index using something like Lucene: http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html

Answer (score 0):

are all the files going to stay as the same name? are any files going to be added, or is it set on 30,00? if all filename stay the same, and  no files are going to be added, i would make an index (maybe index.txt), and explode that to get filenams for keywords.