# PHP: Find keywords recursively in files and return surrounding context as well as filename

Tags: php, regex, recursion

Interesting problem: I search a pile of files and directories for a keyword and my function returns me the filenames as an Array:

```
$files = array();

function search_in_dir($dir, $str) {
    foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir)) as $filename) {
        $files[] = $filename;
    }

    foreach ($files as $k => $file) {
        $source = file_get_contents($file);
        if (strpos($source, $str) === false) {
            unset($files[$k]);
        }
    }
    return array_filter($files);
}

$filenamesWithPaths = search_in_dir("/home/Documents", "testKeyword");
```

The variable `$filenamesWithPaths` contains now an array of the Filenames and the paths. However what I ultimately want to achieve is an associative array or some collection containing the paths with filenames as well as the surrounding text (which is in my case HTML code).

It would be imagineable to return the whole line where the keyword was found and I then further trim it down with other instructions.

Comment: Any reason you want this in PHP? grep has the capabilities for that already - display the relevant line, surrounding context, and the file it was found in.

Comment: True that, Ok my whole app is a Fat-Client JavaScript system, with AJAX/PHP as middleware. SQL I will implement later. I used the grep approach, which works like a bliss, but I think PHP is much more powerful than grep and using shell_exec() would introduce security issues.

Comment: Turns out grep is way more powerful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170201/php-to-search-inside-30-000-text-files So I will start using my grep solution again.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so, [file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) — Reads entire file into an array

You can iterate through each item in a foreach and find your matches.

If the index is 23, it's on line 24.  Simple as that and build your output array how you please.

Comment: I should add, that I have to search 10.000K+ files.

Comment: Doesn't matter, even if it's 10 lines. file_get_contents reads it as a string.  If you want the desired output, you're going to have to split on an end of line delimiter.

Comment: $filestring = file_get_contents($filename);
    $filearray = explode("\n", $filestring);

Comment: @wes one step: `$filearray = file($filename);`. Hopefully the OP's files aren't larger than memory_limit...

Answer (score 0):

Since the Stackoverflow community strongly advises to avoid php for searching functionalities I will use find, which beats grep in performance

```
$search = 'find ' . $directory . ' -type f -exec grep -r ' . $keyword . ' {} + '
shell_exec($search);
```

Store the path+filenames and surrounding context into an collection in php would be the next step. However this is somehow not working:

```
$RESULT = shell_exec('find ' . $domain . ' -type f -exec grep -r ' . $keyword . ' {} + ');

$arr = explode('/index.html:', $RESULT);
```

How to retrieve the path and surrounding context now; as in how to best parse the grep output?